# Why will the syscall will hang for 1min when the Linux audit subsystem reach the backlog limit for the first time?

Tags: audit

I find that when the audit subsystem reach the backlog limit (set via `auditctl -b 1023`) for the first time, the current syscall will hang there for about 1 minute. After 1 minute, the lost counter will be increased and the syscall will return. After the first time, if the backlog limit is reached again, the syscall will return and the lost counter will be increased immediately.

Why will the syscall hang for 1 minute the first time?  This behavior would make the system unusable totally for 1 minute. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The waiting is done [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/audit.c#L1400).

On a recent kernel, you could use `auditctl --backlog_wait_time 0` to set `audit_backlog_wait_time` to 0 to avoid this, but it seems there's nothing we can do on older kernels (e.g. 3.10.104).

Comment: The link is broken